# reload only TR if clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am listing items from SQL in a HTML table `<tr>`'s and `<td>`'s. The table is inside a div that is refreshed with jQuery AJAX in every `30` seconds (that is why the div has a unique id). This part works fine. Here is the HTML:

```js
function auto_load()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/folder/content.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $("#live").html(data);
        } 
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    auto_load(); //Call auto_load() function when DOM is Ready
});
setInterval(auto_load,30000);
```

```html
<div id="live">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
     <tr>
         <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- and so on -->
    </table>
</div>
```

Now what I want to do is make each of the  clickable, but so that if it is clicked,
1) a GET request is sent to a PHP file indicating which particular  was clicked;
2) and only that particular  (or content inside that ) is refreshed right after that, not the whole page.

I cannot do it with a regular http link, as that way if a  is clicked, the whole page would be reloaded.

As this is where my knowledge is short, maybe someone kind can share me some ideas on how to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: So detect a click on a TD, get the id, make an ajax call, replace the HTML. What part are you having the issue with?

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I edited the text a little, referring to TR-s instead of td-s now. The issue is that I don't know much about Javascript and therefore don't even know what to look for. Maybe someone could give me some simple examples.

Comment: you may want to start at reading http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

NOt sure what you want exactly, but if I understand you want to load the row? So you want to listen for a click on the row, read the cells, make an ajax call, and replace the content.

```
$("#live").on("click", "tbody tr", function() {  //listen for click on a table row
    var tr = $(this),  //the row
        tds = tr.find("td"),  //the cells of the row
        id = tds[0].text(),  //the first column text
        output = tds[1]; //where to output

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "some.php",  //where to post the data
        data: { id: id }  //value to pass to the server
    })
    .done(function( result ) {
        output.html(result);   //output the returned value
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    });
});
```

If that is not right, and you want to load the entire table, than you just need to look up the tree to get the div.

```
$(document).on("click", "tr", function() { 
    var div = $(this).closest("div");
    console.log(div.attr("id"));
    div.load("foo.php?id=" + div.attr("id")); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
    $('#myTable').on('click', '.someClass',function () {
        var trID=$(this).attr('id');
        $(this).find('td').append(new Date());//replace this with your AJAX call
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
        <tr id="x" class="someClass"><td>Click Me 1</td></tr>
        <tr id="y" class="someClass"><td>Click Me 2</td></tr>
    <table>
```